# Printing a nested dictionary in a matrix - python

Tags: python, nested, format

Looking for a way to print a nested dictionary as a matrix:

Input

```
nestedD ={'h1': {r1: float1, r2: float2, r3: float3}, 'h2': {r1: float4, r2: float5, r3: float6}, 'h3': {r1: float7, r2: float8, r3: float9}}
```

```
Output
|    |    h1    |    h2    |    h3   |
| -- | -------- | -------- | ------- |
| r1 | float1   | float4   | float7  |
| r2 | float2   | float5   | float8  |
| r3 | float3   | float6   | float9  |
```

[image]

So far I have this:

```
for h, innerD in nestedD.items():
            print (h)
            for r in innerD:
                print("{: >10} {: >10} {: >10}".format(*innerD[r]))
```

TypeError: format() argument after * must be an iterable, not float

How can I iterate through floats of the inner dictionaries using format()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for h, innerD in nestedD.items():
            print (h)
            print("{: >10} {: >10} {: >10}".format(*innerD.values()))
```

So the reason for the error that you are getting is that `innerD[r]` resolves to the number at the address `nestedD[h][r]`. The star passes something you can iterate over (like a list) as the list of parameters to the function.
Since you have 3 format arguments, format should be passed with 3 arguments. In the updated code above the three arguments come from the values of the inner dictionary.

Reading through your question again it seems that still isn't quite what you want. It seems you want to do a kind of rotation on the dictionary first. The answer above will order the values incorrectly.

```py
print("|__| {} | {} | {} |".format(*nestedD.keys()))
headers = nestedD.keys()
# There is an assumption here that all the inner dictionaries have the same keys
rows = nestedD.values[0].keys() 
rotatedD = dict([(row,dict([(header, nestedD[header][row]) for header in headers])) for row in rows])
for key, values in rotatedD:
    str_values = "|".join(["{: >10}".format(v) for v in values])
    print("|{key}|{values}|".format(key=key, values=str_values))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both parts of your answer helped my understanding! I'm a newbie and couldn't wrap my head around it. I tried to implement your suggested code but I get a syntax error in line 5. Could you please elaborate what is happening in line 5 with ```rotatedD```?

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed the syntax error.
You can build up a dictionary as a list of tuples representing the key and the values.
What I have done (perhaps too hurriedly) is take the nested dictionary which is keys by headers followed by rows. I often use the following syntax to help myself understand:

`[header][row] = value`

What that line does is convert it to the following form:

`[row][header] = value`